# Datatables - get the index of the selected rows using fnGetSelectedData

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've created a DataTables live link here to show what I'm trying to do: http://live.datatables.net/dofuxilo/1/

Basically, I'm displaying information to do with the selected rows when you click on the "Currently selected" link - i'm using fnGetSelectedData - i've output a button to each row and I want to use that to deselect the row on the datatable but I'm struggling with how I get the index - there is fnGetSelectedIndexes, but how do I combine that with fnGetSelectedData to both display the data and get the index back?

Hoping this is an easy one and I'm just having a slow Monday morning brain... :)

Many thanks in advance

leddy

Answer (score 0):

Find the below link

http://live.datatables.net/lusuyefu/1/edit

You will be able to unselect the row when you click on cros button.